# MarkLogic 8 NodeJS Angular JSON transaction

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, marklogic

While I have no problem using Postman to PUT data through NodeJS to MarkLogic 8, using Angular I can't get it to work. The `req.body` returns `{}`.

Among the things I've tried are adding this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
```

And:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:9040');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

I have the following function in my controller:

```
function putFabriek($fabriek, $http) {

    var mlUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/fabriek';
    console.log($fabriek);

    $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: mlUrl + '?id=' + $fabriek.id,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        data: JSON.stringify($fabriek)
    }).success(function(data, status) {
        console.log($http.succes);
    }).error(function(data, status) {
        console.log($http.error);
    });     
};
```

In NodeJS I have the following:

```
// Fabrieken Puter
app.put('/fabriek', function (req, res) {
    var inhoud = req.body;
    var fabId  = req.query.id;
    console.log(inhoud);
    db.documents.write(
        { uri: ('/fabrieken/' + fabId + '.json'),
          collections: ['examples', 'metadata-examples'],
          contentType: 'application/json',
          content: inhoud
        })
        .result(null, function(error) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    res.json({ message: 'Fabriek is updated!' });    
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending JSON, so you need to add the relevant JSON body-parser methods.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```